# Сколько Н: "плете(н/нн)ый из тонких ивовых прутьев туесок"?

Tags: орфография, причастия, удвоенные-буквы

***Он упал на плете(н/нн)ый из тонких ивовых прутьев туесок.***

Это классический случай причастия с зависимым словом или опять интересный? Вот не нравится мне вторая Н в ***плетеный***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример самый классический: **плести из прутьев― плетенный из прутьев (прич.)  и плетеный (прилаг.).**

**Причастие опознается по наличию зависимых слов**. ПАС: http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=52#pp52

Примеры из Нацкорпуса

Еще лучше чемодан, **плетенный из ивовых прутьев**. [Елена Певцова. Переносчики настроения (2002) // «Биржа плюс свой дом» (Н. Новгород), 2002.08.12]

Перед уходом на Восточный фронт он подарил мне большущий, **плетенный из лыка** короб с книгами. [А. И. Алдан-Семенов. Бессонница моих странствий (1973)]

Рядом с нею стоял **плетёный** сарайчик, так называемый амшаник, куда ставят улья на зиму. [И. С. Тургенев. Живые мощи (1874)]

По сторонам полотнища в рамке проходит серебристый **плетёный** орнамент. [Олег Агафонов. Знамёнам и штандартам служить бессрочно // «Родина», 2010]

Comment: Кто отказался (укажите конкретно), или Правила Лопатина тоже отменили? Надо сказать, что  формальное правило  4-х признаков, куда входило наличие зависимых слов, имело большое количество исключений, то есть оно было именно ФОРМАЛЬНЫМ.  Правило имело ограниченную область применения, а   именно касалось прилагательных со значением результата действия (крашеный. плетеный и др.). К исключениям из правила относили прилагательные (НН) с общим отношением к действию и причастия, которые не переходили в прилагательные. В общем, это целая тема, всё не перескажешь.

Comment: И вообще, хотелось бы иметь в жизни больше стабильности, особенно в такой области, как грамотное письмо, да еще  при нашем уровне грамотности. Сначала надо правило понять, а потом уже его отменять. Конечно, не всегда у руля знающие люди, но хотя бы приветствовать отмены/перемены не стоит.

Comment: Прошу извинить. Похоже, это я всё напутал. Я лучше удалю свой предыдущий комментарий.